# Is disabling SSLv2 protocol enough to protect against DROWN attacks?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

Is disabling the SSLv2 **protocol** sufficient to protect my application from [DROWN attacks](https://drownattack.com)?

Given the following quote from [OpenSSL.org](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160301.txt)

> Users can avoid this issue by disabling the SSLv2 protocol in all their SSL/TLS
>   servers, if they've not done so already. Disabling all SSLv2 ciphers is also
>   sufficient, provided the patches for CVE-2015-3197 (fixed in OpenSSL 1.0.1r and
>   1.0.2f) have been deployed.  Servers that have not disabled the SSLv2 protocol,
>   and are not patched for CVE-2015-3197 are vulnerable to DROWN even if all SSLv2
>   ciphers are nominally disabled, because malicious clients can force the use of
>   SSLv2 with EXPORT ciphers.

I read this as either a or b:

a) Disable the SSLv2 **Protocol**
or
b) Disable the SSLv2 **Ciphers** + patch with CVE-2015-3197

Obviously the best solution is to update the library, but lets say some apps are already out in the wild with the older unpatched library, however SSLv2 **protocol** has been disabled (not just the *ciphers*, but the actual SSLv2 *protocol* itself is disabled); would the older application be vulnerable even though the SSLv2 protocol is disabled?

---

*I know you must also make sure that the certificate is not used somewhere else that has SSLv2 enabled; but lets assume it is a unique certificate not used elsewhere.*

*and yes i know that SSLv3 should also be disabled for protection from POODLE, but that's not the point of this question.*

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also, SSLv2 should have been disable 15 years ago or so because of other vulnerabilities in the protocol. DROWN is yet another reason in the long line of attacks against the protocol. Also see Loren Weith's [Differences Between SSLv2, SSLv3, and TLS](http://www.yaksman.org/~lweith/ssl.pdf) from 2002. The paper details at least 3 attacks on SSLv2.

Comment: @jww I asked in the context of software I am developing that utilizes a particular library ([tag:openssl]). Yes my question is related to [tag:security] (<- 37k questions tagged security) but it is also related to software development. I fully agree that SSL should have been disabled years ago, and if you actually read my question you will see that it already is disabled in the copies of my application that exists in the wild. The question is about whether or not disabling the protocol is sufficient or if you must also update the library to be considered protected...

Answer (score 2):

As long as you've disabled SSLv2 on all of your servers, they are protected from the DROWN attack.

Note that if you have even one server with SSLv2 enabled, and you share keys - for example by using wildcard certificates, which is very common - then even your servers that have SSLv2 disabled become vulnerable, because the attack can use the one SSLv2 server to attack connections on the other servers using later protocols.

Answer (score 1):

DROWN can only attack servers that use SSLv2. So disabling that protocol will protect that server - providing the same key is not used elsewhere.

However that's not to say there won't be some future vulnerability or bug that effectively re-enables SSLv2 or such like even if you've configured it off, so best to patch or upgrade as well if you can. Latest versions of OpenSSL doesn't even support SSLv2.